# How to use \textwidth (or any variable) in a picture environment

Tags: diagrams, lengths

I don't understand why this doesn't work. I am getting a compile error. Am I missing something?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
        \linethickness{1.5pt}
        \put(0,0){\line(1,0){\textwidth}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

The error is in `\textwidth`. When I put a decimal value (like 137) in, the example compiles correctly. The reason that I want to use `\textwidth` is obvious, I want a line aligned with the text.

Strangely enough, variable expansion does work in a TikZ environment.

Comment: The `\line` macro does expects a length without `pt`, so you could use `\strippt\textwidth` instead (with `\strippt` defined as `\makeatletter\def\strippt{\strip@pt}\makeatother`). Though, in this case it would be easier to just use `\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}`.

Comment: Wow! This is an overwhelming numbers of answers, and really fast! About my user name: I realized I only logged on (using my Google account) but no user name was created. Indeed, user1234 is dull. I changed it to my common name on forums.

Comment: I see what the problem is and why TikZ does accept it. I know I could use \rule, but this is only a MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `picture` environment expects factors for the length `\unitlength`. Package `picture` redefines the `picture` macros to detect length specifications to support them additionally:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{picture}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{picture}(0,0)
        \linethickness{1.5pt}
        \put(0,0){\line(1,0){\textwidth}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be the really easiest solution. I will try it as well. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The `\line` macro expects a length without a unit as it uses `\unitlength` (default: `1pt`) for this parameter (as well to the argument of the `picture` environment which size you have set to `0pt × 0pt` by the way).

Here are three and a fourth possible solution to deal with that. The first one just stripes the `pt` from `\textwidth` so that the `picture` environment can multiply it again with the `\unitlength` of `1pt`.

The second one is similar to the first in that it sets `\unitlength` to `\textwidth` so that the `\line` macro can be used as `\line(1,0){1}`.
The third one goes one step further and sets `\unitlength` to `\textwidth` for the whole `picture` so that even its dimension can be given in `\textwidth` lengths.

The fourth solution simply uses the LaTeX macro `\rule` to mimic the output of your `picture` environment.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\def\strippt{\strip@pt}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{picture}(\strippt\textwidth,0)%
        \linethickness{1.5pt}%
        \put(0,0){\line(1,0){\strippt\textwidth}}
\end{picture}

\noindent
\begin{picture}(\strippt\textwidth,0)%
        \linethickness{1.5pt}%
        \put(0,0){\setlength{\unitlength}{\textwidth}\line(1,0){1}}
\end{picture}

\noindent\begingroup\setlength{\unitlength}{\textwidth}%
\begin{picture}(1,0)%
        \linethickness{1.5pt}%
        \put(0,0){\line(1,0){1}}
\end{picture}
\endgroup

\noindent\rule[-.75pt]{\textwidth}{1.5pt}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]