# Using \textwidth via strip@pt with beamer and the picture environment

Tags: beamer, graphics, diagrams, boxes, lengths

OK, I admit I haven't tried my MWE without Beamer.

My goal is to use e.g `\textwidth` with the picture environment, and my overall goal is to include several rectangular portions of an .eps file within a picture environment.

I was trying to follow @Qrrbrbirlbel's example here:
[How to use \textwidth (or any variable) in a picture environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109522/how-to-use-textwidth-or-any-variable-in-a-picture-environment)

But I can't use his geometry package options with Beamer (not sure if that is the problem, but I guess not).

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[compress,red,notes]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{An overview to constraint-based modeling}

\makeatletter
\def\strippt{\strip@pt}
\makeatother

\newsavebox{\toynet}
\savebox{\toynet}{  
\includegraphics*[width=\textwidth, viewport=0 418 708 718, clip=true]
{SmatExample}  }

\newsavebox{\toySmat}
\savebox{\toySmat}{
\includegraphics*[width=\textwidth, viewport=0 0 708 418, clip=true]
{SmatExample} }

\newsavebox{\FBAgeom}

\begin{picture}(\strippt\textwidth, \strippt\textheight)
\put(0,\strippt\textheight){\usebox{\toynet}}

\end{picture}
} % end of \frame

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
No file test.nav.
<SmatExample.eps> <SmatExample.eps>
! Undefined control sequence.
\strippt ->\strip
                  @pt
l.27 }
       % end of \frame
```

And here is another question I had using the same image (if you want to download the image to work with the MWE):

[How to correctly clip with viewports with includegraphics and beamer columns?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180705/how-to-correctly-clip-with-viewports-with-includegraphics-and-beamer-columns)

Note that in my current example I haven't attempted to use the correct coefficients for `\textwidth` or `\textheight`.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly and what is the question? Or what doesn't work?

Comment: I forgot to include the error, but it doesn't compile. Will update with error message in 15 minutes. As for what I am trying to do, I hope to include several rectangles from an eps file in a picture environment.

Comment: Actually, I would like to include some nonconvex polygonal objects eventually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `picture` extends environment `picture` and related commands to allow length instead of factors for `\unitlength` in their arguments:

```
\documentclass[compress,red,notes]{beamer}
\usepackage{picture}

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{An overview to constraint-based modeling}

\newsavebox{\toynet}
\savebox{\toynet}{
\includegraphics*[width=\textwidth, viewport=0 418 708 718, clip=true]
{SmatExample}  }

\newsavebox{\toySmat}
\savebox{\toySmat}{
\includegraphics*[width=\textwidth, viewport=0 0 708 418, clip=true]
{SmatExample} }

\newsavebox{\FBAgeom}

\begin{picture}(\textwidth, \textheight)
  \put(0,\textheight){\makebox(\textwidth,0)[t]{\usebox{\toynet}}} 
\end{picture}
} % end of \frame
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Answer to the error of the question

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\strippt ->\strip
                  @pt
```

This is a typical error, if `@` has the wrong category code. `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are not working in a normal frame, because the contents of the frame is already parsed and tokenized, *before* the category code are changed. Either move `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` outside the frame or use option `fragile`:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{...}

  \makeatletter
  \def\strippt{\strip@pt}
  \makeatother
  ...
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Should have paid more attention to your post in the linked question.