# Spaces and page break inside a minted listing

Tags: page-breaking, minted

***THIS IS NO DUPLICATED QUESTION*** because I get following error at removing the `listing` environment around my `minted` env.:
ERROR:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the math
-mode dollar sign. This is incompatible with tikz and its calc library and migh
t cause unrecoverable errors.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.17   \PYG{n+nf}{push} \PYG{n+nb}{ebp}
```

===========================================================================

***QUESTION***

I have following latex script:

```
% page 6
\sffamily
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[trim={1in 1in 1in 1in}, clip, scale = 0.5]{stack_block}
  \caption{stack\_block.png}
\end{figure}
\noindent
Der Stack ist inkrementiert aufgebaut. D.h., dass er von der größten zur kleinsten Adresse \textit{aufsteigt}. In der Illustration ist die Speicherplatzreservierung sowie die Operation mit Variablen gekennzeichnet. Um direkten Zugriff auf Variablen aus dem Stack zu haben, muss bevor die Variable in den Stack geschrieben wird, der \textit{Stack Bottom Pointer (EBP)} auf die aktuelle Adresse des \textit{Stack Pointers (ESP)} gesetzt werden. Anschließend wird ein beliebiger Wert per \textit{push register} in den Stack verschoben. Dabei wird der Wert aus \textit{register} an die Position \textit{ESP} geschrieben und \textit{ESP} wird um die Speichergröße von \textit{register} dekrementiert.
\newline
Nachfolgend ist ein Assembler Code, der die Operationen mit dem Stack verdeutlicht, dargestellt. Dieser ist in NASM geschrieben und für 32bit Systeme.
\ttfamily\setstretch{1.0}
\begin{listing}[ht]
\begin{minted}[
xleftmargin=0.4in,
linenos
]{nasm}
; test.asm
; TEST
; ---------
;
; nasm -f elf test.asm
; ld -m elf_i386 -s -o test test.o

section .data

section .bss

section .text
GLOBAL _start

_start:
  push ebp

  mov ebp, esp

  mov ecx, dword 01h
  push ecx

  mov eax, [ebp - 4]
  mov ebx, 01h

  mov esp, ebp
  pop ebp

  cmp ebx, eax
  je exit

  mov ebx, 1
  mov al, 1
  int 80h

 exit:
  xor ebx, ebx
  mov al, 1
  int 80h
\end{minted}
\caption{test.asm}
\end{listing}
\setstretch{1.5}
```

when I put the code listing onto a new page, it starts directly at the top. But with the current setting, it looks like:

[image: here]

but what I want is a direct start under the last line of text and the code listing should be broken over the page break. how?

***EDIT: EXAMPLE CODE***

Here my latex code so you can test it by your self. I am using xelatex and the problem occurs at end of the document (last page).

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% compile with: xelatex --shell-escape [file.tex]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% page setup
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% package imports
\usepackage{fontspec}                         % font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % encoding
\usepackage{minted}                           % syntax highlighting
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                         % headers/ footers
\usepackage[margin=0.89in]{geometry}          % page margins setup
\usepackage{lastpage}                         % number of last page
\usepackage{graphicx}                         % to embed graphics
\usepackage{tikz}                             % to draw geometrics
\usepackage{eso-pic}                          % add picture/background commands to each page
\usepackage{xcolor}                           % colors
\usepackage{titlesec}                         % paragraph and section formatting
\usepackage{setspace}                         % line spacing

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% configurations

% font setup
\setsansfont{Ubuntu}       % Sans: Ubuntu - use \sffamily or \textsf{}
\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}  % typewriter: Ubuntu Mono - use \ttfamily or \texttt{}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=0.95]{Ubuntu}

% graphics path
\graphicspath{{resources/}}

% minted theme
\usemintedstyle{pastie} % monokai, add to minted options: bgcolor=bggray
% monokai: \renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{\ttfamily\textcolor[rgb]{0.48,0.48,0.48}{\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}
\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{\ttfamily\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}

% color definitions
% monokai
% \definecolor{bggray}{cmyk}{0.03, 0.0, 0.15, 0.84}

% section/paragraph styling
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\bfseries\sffamily}

% lists
\renewcommand\contentsname{Inhalt}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Bilder}
\renewcommand\figurename{Bild}
\renewcommand\listoflistingscaption{Programmcodes}
\renewcommand\listingscaption{Programmcode}

\newcommand\ownit[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0.28,1}{\textit{#1}}}

% line spacing
\setstretch{1.5}

% enable tikz coordinate calculation
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% defining tab
\newcommand\tab[1][0.2in]{\hspace*{#1}}

% page borders
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[line width=2pt]
      ($ (current page.north west) + (0.79in, -0.79in) $)
      rectangle
      ($ (current page.south east) + (-0.79in, 0.79in) $);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

% headers/footers
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}     % footer line width
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}     % header line width
\pagestyle{fancyplain}                 % headers/footers on all pages
\lhead{\sffamily{\textbf{Exploiting Seminar}}} % left header content
\chead{}
\rhead{\sffamily{\input{"|resources/dater.sh"}}}                                        % right header content
\lfoot{\sffamily{Credits: Prutheus $\rightarrow$ www.prutheus.com / mail@prutheus.com}} % left footer content
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\sffamily{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}} % right footer content

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% document start
\begin{document}

% title page
\sffamily
\title{\textbf{Exploiting Seminar}}
\author{Prutheus}
\date{\input{"|resources/dater.sh"}}

\maketitle

\vspace*\fill
\begin{figure}[h]
  \flushright
  \includegraphics[trim={0 0.5in 0 0}, scale = 1.0]{sign}
\end{figure}
\begin{flushright}
  \textcolor[rgb]{0.6,0.6,0.66}{\rule{1.5in}{0.8pt}}
\end{flushright}

\newpage

% page 2
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoflistings

\newpage

% page 3
\sffamily
\section{Zusammenfassung}
In dem \ownit{Exploiting Seminar} werden grundlegende Fähigkeiten im Bereich des \ownit{Exploiting} gelehrt. Dabei wird die Funktionsweise von Programmen auf Rechnern dargestellt, sowie der Eingriff in den Prozessablauf. Um dieses Vorhaben realisieren zu können, wird Assembler-Programmierung hinsichtlicht der Erstellung von \ownit{Shellcodes} präsentiert.
\section{Ziel}
Ziel des \ownit{Exploiting Seminars} ist die Vermittlung von Kernkompetenzen im Bereich des Prozessablaufes von Programmen sowie der zielgerichtete Eingriff in die Prozessfunktionalität.

\newpage

% page 4
\sffamily
\section{Programmstart}
Bei einem \ownit{Programmstart} wird der Maschinencode eines Programms in den Arbeitsspeicher geladen und schrittweise abgearbeitet. Dabei gilt es folgende Bereiche eines Programms zu unterscheiden:
\subsection{Speichersektionen}
\subsubsection{section .data:\tab\ownit{Datenbereich}}
Im \ownit{Datenebreich} werden zum Start geladene Daten oder Konstanten deklariert. Dabei wird eine fixe Speicherregion reserviert, welche später nicht mehr expandiert werden kann. Während der Prozesslaufzeit können diese Daten nicht mehr geändert werden.
\subsubsection{section .bss:\tab\ownit{Variablenbereich}}
Im \ownit{Variablenbereich} werden Variablen deklariert. Das heißt es wird eine vordefinierte Speicherblockgröße für Daten, welche während der Prozesslaufzeit beschrieben und gelesen werden können, im Arbeitsspeicher reserviert. Diese Puffer-Speicherregion wird mit Nullen gefüllt.
\subsubsection{section .text:\tab\ownit{Programmbereich}}
Im \ownit{Programmbereich} wird der aktuelle Programmcode hinterlegt. Zu Beginn dieses Bereiches wird außerdem der Programmeinstiegspunkt für den Kernel festgelegt. Die Sektionsgröße wird fixiert, eine spätere Expansion ist nicht möglich.
\subsection{Speichersegmente}
Der Systemspeicher wird in sogenannte \ownit{Speichersegmente} aufgeteilt.
\subsection{Datensegment}
Das \ownit{Datensegment} setzt sich aus den .data und den .bss Sektionen zusammen.
\subsection{Codesegment}
Das \ownit{Codesegment} besteht aus der .text Sektion.
\subsection{Stack}
Der \ownit{Stack} beinhaltet Daten und Werte, welche im laufenden Programm zwischen Funktionsaufrufen ausgetauscht werden.

\newpage

% page 5
\sffamily
\section{Stack}
Da der Stack eine wichtige Funktion beim \ownit{Shellcoding} und \ownit{Injecting} darstellt, wird dieser nun ausführlicher betrachtet.\newline
Der Stack belegt, wie bereits erwähnt, nur einen Teil des Speichers der für die Programmausführung reserviert wird. Hier eine schematische Darstellung des gesamten Speicherblocks:
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[trim={1.7in 1.7in 1.7in 1.7in}, clip, scale = 0.5]{memory_block}
  \caption{memory\_block.png}
\end{figure}
\newline
Wird der Stack nun genauer betrachtet, so stellt man fest, dass dieser nochmals unterteilt ist, in einzelne \ownit{Spei-cheradressen}. Dabei ist die maximale Anzahl an Bits, die in einer Adresse hinterlegt werden können, genauso groß, wie die Rechengröße des verbauten Prozessors. Da im \ownit{Exploiting Seminar} hauptsächlich \ownit{Shellcodes} für 32bit Prozessoren entwickelt werden, ist somit die Speichergröße einer Adresse auf 32bit, also 4 Bytes bzw. einem double word (\ownit{dword}) begrenzt. Hier eine Datstellung des Stacks:

\newpage

% page 6
\sffamily
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[trim={1in 1in 1in 1in}, clip, scale = 0.5]{stack_block}
  \caption{stack\_block.png}
\end{figure}
\noindent
Der Stack ist inkrementiert aufgebaut. D.h., dass er von der größten zur kleinsten Adresse \ownit{aufsteigt}. In der Illustration ist die Speicherplatzreservierung sowie die Operation mit Variablen gekennzeichnet. Um direkten Zugriff auf Variablen aus dem Stack zu haben, muss bevor die Variable in den Stack geschrieben wird, der \ownit{Stack Bottom Pointer (EBP)} auf die aktuelle Adresse des \ownit{Stack Pointers (ESP)} gesetzt werden. Anschließend wird ein beliebiger Wert per \ownit{push register} in den Stack verschoben. Dabei wird der Wert aus \ownit{register} an die Position \ownit{ESP} geschrieben und \ownit{ESP} wird um die Speichergröße von \ownit{register} dekrementiert.
\newline
Nachfolgend ist ein Assembler Code, der die Operationen mit dem Stack verdeutlicht, dargestellt. Dieser ist in NASM geschrieben und für 32bit Systeme.
\ttfamily\setstretch{1.0}
\begin{listing}[h]
\begin{minted}[
xleftmargin=0.4in,
linenos
]{nasm}
; test.asm
; TEST
; ---------
;
; nasm -f elf test.asm
; ld -m elf_i386 -s -o test test.o

section .data

section .bss

section .text
GLOBAL _start

_start:
  push ebp

  mov ebp, esp

  mov ecx, dword 01h
  push ecx

  mov eax, [ebp - 4]
  mov ebx, 01h

  mov esp, ebp
  pop ebp

  cmp ebx, eax
  je exit

  mov ebx, 1
  mov al, 1
  int 80h

 exit:
  xor ebx, ebx
  mov al, 1
  int 80h
\end{minted}
\caption{test.asm}
\end{listing}
\setstretch{1.5}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% document end
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, maybe you can help me solving my problem?

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would help that others can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I have added code now, please check yourself!

Comment: `listing` is a floating environment that cannot break across pages. (And by the way, your example is not minimal, most of the code and contents is actually irrelevant for the question you ask.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. so what else should I use instead of listing?

Comment: I can't figure out what causes the error you got after removing the `listing` environment, but it seems it's some interaction with the page border you draw and `minted`. Some completely unrelated comments though: 1) Instead of all the `\sffamily`s in the document, just add `\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}` in the preamble. 2) Don't load `inputenc` with `fontspec`/`xelatex` documents. 3) On the front page, I don't think you need the `figure` environment. 4) Instead of the `\ttfamily` before the code listing, add `fontfamily=tt` to the options of the `minted` environment.

Comment: You probably need to remove a `\ttfamily` placed before some listing.

Comment: @ArashEsbati When I wanna remove the `listing` environment around my minted, I get the error at compiling: `! Package tikz Error: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the math
-mode dollar sign. This is incompatible with tikz and its calc library and migh
t cause unrecoverable errors.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 ...{p}{,} \PYG{k+kt}{dword} \PYG{l+m+mh}{01h}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem occurs because `listing` is an environment that doesn't allow pagebreaks. One option could be to remove the `listing` environment, and use `\captionof` from the `caption` package, which allows you to add captions outside of floating environments like `listing`.

Now, there appears to be some sort of clash between the `tikzpicture` used to draw the frame in the `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` and `minted`, or at least a `minted` code listing that breaks across pages. One way around that could be to not use TikZ for the frame, but, for example, good old `picture` mode. Note that to be able to use `\paperheight` etc. in the length of the `\line`s, I loaded the `picture` package, cf. [How to use \textwidth (or any variable) in a picture environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109522/how-to-use-textwidth-or-any-variable-in-a-picture-environment).

The frame-drawing code I came up with is as follows:

```
% page borders
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\linethickness{2pt}
\put(\dimexpr0.79in-1pt,0.79in){\line(1,0){\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.79in-0.79in+1pt}}
\put(0.79in,\dimexpr0.79in-1pt){\line(0,1){\dimexpr\paperheight-0.79in-0.79in+1pt}}
\put(\dimexpr0.79in-1pt,\dimexpr\paperheight-0.79in){\line(1,0){\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.79in-0.79in+1pt}}
\put(\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.79in,\dimexpr0.79in-1pt){\line(0,1){\dimexpr\paperheight-0.79in-0.79in+2pt}}
\end{picture}%
```

Complete working code below. I also implemented the suggestions I mentioned in a comment above:

- Removed the `inputenc` package. `xelatex` (and `lualatex`) assumes `utf8`, and `inputenc` should not be used.
- Removed the `figure` environment on the title page. You don't need a `figure` environment to use `\includegraphics`, seems here like the `flushright` environment alone should be sufficient.
- Instead of having a `\sffamily` every page (which is redundant in the first place, the one you have right after `\begin{document}` will affect everything that comes after it), I added `\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}` to the preamble, which sets sans serif as default.
- For the `minted` code block, instead of the `\ttfamily` preceding it, I added `fontfamily=tt` to the environment options.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% compile with: xelatex --shell-escape [file.tex]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% page setup
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, demo]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% package imports
\usepackage{fontspec}                         % font
\usepackage{minted}                           % syntax highlighting
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                         % headers/ footers
\usepackage[margin=0.89in]{geometry}          % page margins setup
\usepackage{lastpage}                         % number of last page
\usepackage{graphicx}                         % to embed graphics
\usepackage{eso-pic}                          % add picture/background commands to each page
\usepackage{xcolor}                           % colors
\usepackage{titlesec}                         % paragraph and section formatting
\usepackage{setspace}                         % line spacing
\usepackage{caption} % for \captionof (and caption customization)
\usepackage{picture} % allows for use of lengths directly in picture-environments


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% configurations

% font setup
\setsansfont{Ubuntu}       % Sans: Ubuntu - use \sffamily or \textsf{}
\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}  % typewriter: Ubuntu Mono - use \ttfamily or \texttt{}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=0.95]{Ubuntu}

% graphics path
\graphicspath{{resources/}}

% minted theme
\usemintedstyle{pastie} % monokai, add to minted options: bgcolor=bggray
% monokai: \renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{\ttfamily\textcolor[rgb]{0.48,0.48,0.48}{\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}
\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{\ttfamily\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}

% color definitions
% monokai
% \definecolor{bggray}{cmyk}{0.03, 0.0, 0.15, 0.84}

% section/paragraph styling
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\bfseries\sffamily}

% lists
\renewcommand\contentsname{Inhalt}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Bilder}
\renewcommand\figurename{Bild}
\renewcommand\listoflistingscaption{Programmcodes}
\renewcommand\listingscaption{Programmcode}

\newcommand\ownit[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0.28,1}{\textit{#1}}}

% line spacing
\setstretch{1.5}


% defining tab
\newcommand\tab[1][0.2in]{\hspace*{#1}}

% page borders
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\linethickness{2pt}
\put(\dimexpr0.79in-1pt,0.79in){\line(1,0){\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.79in-0.79in+1pt}}
\put(0.79in,\dimexpr0.79in-1pt){\line(0,1){\dimexpr\paperheight-0.79in-0.79in+1pt}}
\put(\dimexpr0.79in-1pt,\dimexpr\paperheight-0.79in){\line(1,0){\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.79in-0.79in+1pt}}
\put(\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.79in,\dimexpr0.79in-1pt){\line(0,1){\dimexpr\paperheight-0.79in-0.79in+2pt}}
\end{picture}%

}

% headers/footers
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}     % footer line width
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}     % header line width
\pagestyle{fancyplain}                 % headers/footers on all pages
\lhead{\sffamily{\textbf{Exploiting Seminar}}} % left header content
\chead{}
\rhead{\sffamily{\input{"|resources/dater.sh"}}}                                        % right header content
\lfoot{\sffamily{Credits: Prutheus $\rightarrow$ www.prutheus.com / mail@prutheus.com}} % left footer content
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\sffamily{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}} % right footer content

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% document start

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\title{\textbf{Exploiting Seminar}}
\author{Prutheus}
\date{\input{"|resources/dater.sh"}}

\begin{document}

% title page

\maketitle

\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{flushright}
  \includegraphics[trim={0 0.5in 0 0}, scale = 1.0]{sign}

  \textcolor[rgb]{0.6,0.6,0.66}{\rule{1.5in}{0.8pt}}
\end{flushright}

\clearpage
% page 2
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoflistings

\clearpage

% page 3
\section{Zusammenfassung}
In dem \ownit{Exploiting Seminar} werden grundlegende Fähigkeiten im Bereich des \ownit{Exploiting} gelehrt. Dabei wird die Funktionsweise von Programmen auf Rechnern dargestellt, sowie der Eingriff in den Prozessablauf. Um dieses Vorhaben realisieren zu können, wird Assembler-Programmierung hinsichtlicht der Erstellung von \ownit{Shellcodes} präsentiert.

\section{Ziel}
Ziel des \ownit{Exploiting Seminars} ist die Vermittlung von Kernkompetenzen im Bereich des Prozessablaufes von Programmen sowie der zielgerichtete Eingriff in die Prozessfunktionalität.



% page 4
\section{Programmstart}
Bei einem \ownit{Programmstart} wird der Maschinencode eines Programms in den Arbeitsspeicher geladen und schrittweise abgearbeitet. Dabei gilt es folgende Bereiche eines Programms zu unterscheiden:

\subsection{Speichersektionen}
\subsubsection{section .data:\tab\ownit{Datenbereich}}

Im \ownit{Datenebreich} werden zum Start geladene Daten oder Konstanten deklariert. Dabei wird eine fixe Speicherregion reserviert, welche später nicht mehr expandiert werden kann. Während der Prozesslaufzeit können diese Daten nicht mehr geändert werden.

\subsubsection{section .bss:\tab\ownit{Variablenbereich}}
Im \ownit{Variablenbereich} werden Variablen deklariert. Das heißt es wird eine vordefinierte Speicherblockgröße für Daten, welche während der Prozesslaufzeit beschrieben und gelesen werden können, im Arbeitsspeicher reserviert. Diese Puffer-Speicherregion wird mit Nullen gefüllt.

\subsubsection{section .text:\tab\ownit{Programmbereich}}
Im \ownit{Programmbereich} wird der aktuelle Programmcode hinterlegt. Zu Beginn dieses Bereiches wird außerdem der Programmeinstiegspunkt für den Kernel festgelegt. Die Sektionsgröße wird fixiert, eine spätere Expansion ist nicht möglich.

\subsection{Speichersegmente}
Der Systemspeicher wird in sogenannte \ownit{Speichersegmente} aufgeteilt.

\subsection{Datensegment}
Das \ownit{Datensegment} setzt sich aus den .data und den .bss Sektionen zusammen.

\subsection{Codesegment}
Das \ownit{Codesegment} besteht aus der .text Sektion.

\subsection{Stack}
Der \ownit{Stack} beinhaltet Daten und Werte, welche im laufenden Programm zwischen Funktionsaufrufen ausgetauscht werden.

% page 5
\section{Stack}
Da der Stack eine wichtige Funktion beim \ownit{Shellcoding} und \ownit{Injecting} darstellt, wird dieser nun ausführlicher betrachtet.\newline
Der Stack belegt, wie bereits erwähnt, nur einen Teil des Speichers der für die Programmausführung reserviert wird. Hier eine schematische Darstellung des gesamten Speicherblocks:
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[trim={1.7in 1.7in 1.7in 1.7in}, clip, scale = 0.5]{memory_block}
  \caption{memory\_block.png}
\end{figure}
Wird der Stack nun genauer betrachtet, so stellt man fest, dass dieser nochmals unterteilt ist, in einzelne \ownit{Spei-cheradressen}. Dabei ist die maximale Anzahl an Bits, die in einer Adresse hinterlegt werden können, genauso groß, wie die Rechengröße des verbauten Prozessors. Da im \ownit{Exploiting Seminar} hauptsächlich \ownit{Shellcodes} für 32bit Prozessoren entwickelt werden, ist somit die Speichergröße einer Adresse auf 32bit, also 4 Bytes bzw. einem double word (\ownit{dword}) begrenzt. Hier eine Datstellung des Stacks:



% page 6
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[trim={1in 1in 1in 1in}, clip, scale = 0.5]{stack_block}
  \caption{stack\_block.png}
\end{figure}


Der Stack ist inkrementiert aufgebaut. D.h., dass er von der größten zur kleinsten Adresse \ownit{aufsteigt}. In der Illustration ist die Speicherplatzreservierung sowie die Operation mit Variablen gekennzeichnet. Um direkten Zugriff auf Variablen aus dem Stack zu haben, muss bevor die Variable in den Stack geschrieben wird, der \ownit{Stack Bottom Pointer (EBP)} auf die aktuelle Adresse des \ownit{Stack Pointers (ESP)} gesetzt werden. Anschließend wird ein beliebiger Wert per \ownit{push register} in den Stack verschoben. Dabei wird der Wert aus \ownit{register} an die Position \ownit{ESP} geschrieben und \ownit{ESP} wird um die Speichergröße von \ownit{register} dekrementiert.


Nachfolgend ist ein Assembler Code, der die Operationen mit dem Stack verdeutlicht, dargestellt. Dieser ist in NASM geschrieben und für 32bit Systeme.

\begin{minted}[
xleftmargin=0.4in,
linenos,
fontfamily=tt
]{nasm}
; test.asm
; TEST
; ---------
;
; nasm -f elf test.asm
; ld -m elf_i386 -s -o test test.o

section .data

section .bss

section .text
GLOBAL _start

_start:
  push ebp

  mov ebp, esp

  mov ecx, dword 01h
  push ecx

  mov eax, [ebp - 4]
  mov ebx, 01h

  mov esp, ebp
  pop ebp

  cmp ebx, eax
  je exit

  mov ebx, 1
  mov al, 1
  int 80h

 exit:
  xor ebx, ebx
  mov al, 1
  int 80h
\end{minted}
\captionof{listing}{test.asm}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% document end
\end{document}
```

The last two pages of output:

[image]